# Mouseenter and mouseleave flashing

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I mouseeneter the box becomes visible but then it keeps fading on and off even tho my mouse stays on the box, what am I doing wrong?

jQuery

```
    geoThumb = $(".geoThumb");
    geoThumb.each(function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(".infoBox").fadeIn(500);
        }).mouseleave(function(){
            $(".infoBox").fadeOut(500);     
        });
    });
```

Comment: You'll need to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this, so we can see the issue, but most likely your mouse pointer ends up on the infoBox once it's faded in, and that again triggers the fadeOut, and once the infoBox is gone, the mouse is back on geoThumb, and it all starts over again, which makes it flash.

Comment: ok i think you just answered my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut`.

```
$(".geoThumb").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".infoBox").stop().fadeIn(500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".infoBox").stop().fadeOut(500);     
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/R4F9T/

It flashes because the animations are queued when the animations before it are not finished. To prevent this behavior, [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is designed and you can use this to clear all queued animations.

> Quote from jQuery Docs
>
> The usefulness of the .stop() method is evident when we need to animate an element on mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: box isn't fading at all with this

Comment: @rob.m - There was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

.mouseenter and .mouseleave isn't the most powerful way to handle hover events in query. Try using .hover() which takes 2 functions, the first one runs when the mouse enters the element and one when it leaves. http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: hover is same as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` combined. it is just a pseudo event.

Comment: @PSL, I know, but .hover() is a lot more succinct

Comment: @ColinMcGrath Why do you think so. It is just the same.... What OP is doing and using hover is no different. OP could also just do `$(".geoThumb").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(".infoBox").fadeToggle(500);
});`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `each()` at all.
Use `.hover()` (in this specific case)
Use `.stop()` to clear previous animation buildups on every new event.
Use `.fadeToggle()`  (in combination with .hover())

```
geoThumb = $(".geoThumb");

geoThumb.hover(function() {
     $(".infoBox").stop().fadeToggle();
});
```

Also I'm not sure if you're specific enough with your `$(".infoBox")` selector, cause it's a collection of **all** `.infobox` elements, if you need to animate only one specific element you need to take a look at some other DOM *traversal* methods like `.find()`